# How to read MacBook Air (2013) SSD via PCI card adapter from Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, macbook, macbook-air

I purchased an adapter which connects my MacBook Air (2013) SSD to PCI-E of motherboard.

[image]

However, I was unable to find a proper way to read it, even with MacDrive.

What I want to do is back up the files off of this SSD as my MacBook Air has been damaged and unable to boot.

Is there any recommended solution?

[image]

Comment: Is there a driver for that adapter? Make and model of adapter?

Comment: "my Macbook air has been damaged and unable to boot."  In that case, are you sure the SSD isn't broken and/or corrupted?

Comment: Try UFS Explorer https://www.ufsexplorer.com/ufs-explorer-standard-recovery/

Answer (score 0):

Mac drives are formatted as HFS filesystem. You need software like [Disk Internals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) to read the partitions. However you will be unable to write on the disk in its format.

To make the disk work again in Mac you'll need to make a bootable USB drive with Mac OS system (maybe BootCamp) to format the drive and install system.

Comment: MacDrive does that also, they have another issue.

Comment: thank you for your quick replay! I want to ask if my data stored in ssd will be lost if I have followed the steps?

Comment: @Moab Hello, thank you for the feedback, I have tried MacDrive before, however, I was stuck at image 2 as initialize disk comes with warning of data erase

Comment: You going to answer my questions in the comment above?

Comment: @Moab yes as I have tried MacDrive before, it comes with warning. The data stored was very very important to my family, hope you can understand...

Comment: Again, "Is there a driver for that adapter? Make and model of adapter?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44015/discussion-between-edwardddddd-and-moab).

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into an issue with Apple's CoreStorage volumes.  CoreStorage became the default format when reinstalling OS X as of Mavericks, and Yosemite outright converted your system to it during upgrades.

CoreStorage volumes are to Apple what Dynamic Disks are to Windows -- a proprietary container format for your partitions.  The underlying file system is still HFS+, but the HFS+ volume is wrapped in a CoreStorage partition that few Windows-based HFS+ drivers understand.  MacDisk does support them, but only if you are running version 9.3.2.6 or later.

Check your version of MacDisk.  It looks from the screenshot above that it doesn't understand what `(partition2)` is.  It is very likely a CoreStorage volume.

Comment: Hello, I still remember I got Ubuntu installed and I give it a try, and things seems to be clearer, here's the screenshot of the partition that Ubuntu has successfully read.
https://postimg.org/image/w4kbgauux/

Comment: Is there a way that I can extract my data(in partition 2, I guess?)  back in Linux / Windows?

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting that Ubuntu knows exactly what that partition is.  I don't know how deep that support goes though, or whether Ubuntu could mount it.  The only way to get your data back for sure would be to put the drive back into the Mac and use OS X to copy it somewhere.